# using an empty array as a parameter for execute

Tags: php, pdo

I was reader about `PDO` , and I was wondering what is the deference between those two methods:

```
public function query($sql)
    {
        $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $req->execute();
        return $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

public function query($sql, $data  = array())
    {
        $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $req->execute($data);
        return $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
```

In the second method, `execute` has an empty array as a parameter and the first one doesn't, what is the role of using an empty array as a parameter for `execute` ?

Comment: people can always pass second parameter in second query() function, I can't understand much from this piece of code...

Comment: Did you post this question after reading the [documentation page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)? It lists there what are the arguments for the method. Maybe something was not clear from there?

Comment: First one is wrong and second one is right. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is only empty by default. You can pass values in that array and they will be inserted into your SQL statement appropriately (ie - array key=>field name).

Defining an empty array in the function parameters states that this is an *optional* parameter and you are not forced to pass it - only when it is relevant. For example, when performing an INSERT command. If you don't pass any value to the `$data` parameter, it's default value will simply be an empty array.

An example of using default parameters -

```
function saySomething($text="Hello World!"){
  echo $text;
}

saySomething(); // will echo out the default "Hello World!"
saySomething("Goodbye World!"); // will echo out "Goodbye World!" as specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add you parameter bindings in an array instead of using the bindParam() function beforehand.

for instance you wanna select something by id

```
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE `id` = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($id));
```

is the same as

```
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE `id` = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Though for the bindParam function you can check better, 
Check [PHP Manual PDO::excute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Answer (score 1):

First one lets you to run a query without parameters.
Second one lets you to run a query either with parameters or without:

```
$data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table"); 
$data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?",array($id));
```

both works.